# Is there a way to manually record video with Cypress?

Tags: video-capture, cypress

I'd like to record video clips at specified points while Cypress carries out its tests. I see it's possible to take manual screenshots, but it doesn't seem this applies to videos too.

Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find a way of doing that, but maybe you can check [cypress-movie](https://github.com/bahmutov/cypress-movie). It allows you to record (to MP4 and GIF) any test, without the log panel.